# When entering value into TextInput the keyboard closes immediatly

Tags: typescript, react-native

As soon as i try to enter a value into my TextInput the keyboard on mobile closes and the value is not displayed in the TextField. This happens as soon as i use the useState hook to save the input in a variable.

Is there a way to remove this behaviour? I am using ReactNative in TypeScript

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState("");

<TextInput style={styles.text} onChangeText={setLogin} />
```

These should be the relevant code lines

Wanted behaviour would obviously be to be able to fill in the whole input instead of a single character and have it displayed correctly

EDIT: using the defaultValue prop fixed the displaying of the input. The closing keyboard still is a thing!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState("");

<TextInput style={styles.text} onChangeText={(e) => setLogin(e)} value={login} />
```